# Ebay Api, getOrders. Can't get buyer email

Tags: php, ebay-api

Everybody.

Have a question about ebay trading api.

I'm trying to get all orders for authorized user.
I'm developing my web application using PHP.

So, I use this sdk: 
https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php

I'm getting list using getOrders method:

http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/GetOrders.html

Here is my code example:

```
public function getOrders(){
        $service = $this->getTradingService();

        $args = array(
            //"OrderStatus"   => "Completed",
            "OrderStatus"   => "All",
            "SortingOrder"  => "Ascending",
            "OrderRole"     => "Seller",

            //"CreateTimeFrom"   => new \DateTime('2015-01-01'),
            "CreateTimeFrom"   => new \DateTime('2000-01-01'),
            "CreateTimeTo"   => new \DateTime(),
        );

        $request = new Types\GetOrdersRequestType($args);
        $request->RequesterCredentials = new Types\CustomSecurityHeaderType();
        $request->RequesterCredentials->eBayAuthToken = $this->userToken;
        $request->IncludeFinalValueFee = true;
        $request->Pagination = new Types\PaginationType();
        $request->Pagination->EntriesPerPage = 100;
        $pageNum = 1;

        $orders = [];

        do {
            $request->Pagination->PageNumber = $pageNum;

            $response = $service->getOrders($request);

            if (isset($response->Errors)) {

                $message = '';

                foreach ($response->Errors as $error) {
                    $message .= $error->ShortMessage;
                }

                throw new Exception($message);
            }

            if ($response->Ack !== 'Failure' && isset($response->OrderArray)) {
                foreach ($response->OrderArray->Order as $order) {
                    $orders[] = $order->toArray();
                }
            }

            $pageNum += 1;
        }
        while(isset($response->OrderArray) && $pageNum <= $response->PaginationResult->TotalNumberOfPages);

        return $orders;
}
```

It works fine for me except one issue.
I can't get buyer email.

```
$orders[0]['ShippingAddress']['ExternalAddressID']
```

Is empty.

```
$orders[0]['TransactionArray']['Transaction'][0]['Buyer']['Email']
```

Is string value "Invalid Request"

If somebody knows way to get buyers emails.

Or just get informatioan about many users in one request(so I could simply merge them).

UPDATE:

Also tried to do the same without SDK.

```
public function getOrders2(){
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
                  <CreateTimeFrom>2000-01-01T00:00:00</CreateTimeFrom>
                  <CreateTimeTo>2015-10-22T00:00:00</CreateTimeTo>
                  <IncludeFinalValueFee>true</IncludeFinalValueFee>
                  <OrderRole>Seller</OrderRole>
                  <OrderStatus>All</OrderStatus>
                  <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
                  <RequesterCredentials>
                    <eBayAuthToken>' . $this->userToken . '</eBayAuthToken>
                  </RequesterCredentials>
                </GetOrdersRequest>';

        $url = 'https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll';
        $results = $this->sendPostRequest($xml,$url);
        $results = new SimpleXMLElement($results);
        return $results;
    }
```

Get the same issue.

Thanks

Comment: Tried GetUser Api method, also can't get email. Get Invalid request string instead

Comment: about 5% of the time i also get an empty e-mail field. if you are doing this in order to contact the buyer, one workaround would be to use the AddMemberMessageAAQToPartner call

Comment: I get empty emails for any order. But orders was completed for bout 1 year ago.

Comment: Maybe because of that. I jut need to import orders to my crm system and email is required field there.

Comment: if you need some sort of e-mail identifier, you might want to use StaticAlias, which takes the form of an e-mail address e.g <user>@members.ebay.com.

Comment: @faustus Do you know how I can get the actual email address instead of members.ebay.com? I need the actual email address for our couriers!

Comment: @AmirNo-Family i have not looked at this in a while, but from recollection, no, because it is susceptible to abuse. i think the best bet would be to have them enter their e-mail in a comments field. alternatively, and i think this would be a better solution, is to use the PayPal API which should provide e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Need change **SiteID** to id User Registration.

```
$config = [
            'apiVersion' => Services\TradingService::API_VERSION,
            'siteId' => Constants\SiteIds::US, 
            'credentials' => [
                'appId'  => getenv('EBAY_APP_ID'),
                'certId' => getenv('EBAY_CERT_ID'),
                'devId'  => getenv('EBAY_DEV_ID')
            ],
            'sandbox' => false
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order is too old then it will will result in Invalid Request ( Simply saying " This orders is XX days old and we wont provide email address for it )

Answer (score 0):

Ebay withholds their user's email information 14 days after the order is placed.

If you are using their APIs to pulling order info after that you get:

Email = 'Invalild Request'

Example response ...

```
...
'TransactionArray': {'Transaction': [...
                                     'Buyer': {'Email': 'Invalid Request',
                                               'UserFirstName': None,
                                               'UserLastName': None},
...
```

The thing to do is

1. Pull the data before that, and then
2. Do not update the order email data on subsequent data pulls.

I found this out the hard way.   I don't recall reading about that in the API docs.